# Two models estimated using two different, but strongly related predictors (r > 0.99) yielding different results

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

This isn't a problem with correlation between predictors - I have two models, each considers only one of the variables. That is the only difference between the models.

I'm estimating the probability of an diagnosis given some confounders and a measure of monthly temperature. I have two possible temperature definitions I'm considering: monthly average temperature and monthly average *high* temperature. I don't expect the response to temperature to be linear, so I broke average temperature into 5 degree bins with bottom and top coding at < 40 and > 90. I did the same with average high temperature but shifted the bins slightly with bottom and top coding < 50 and > 100.

I estimate the first logistic model

```
event ~ age + sex + ... + mean_temp_group
```

and get the response I'd expect from my theorized process. However, I'd prefer to report the results using mean high temperature since average temperature is misleadingly low (average temp of 70, for instance, is pretty warm with highs in the 80s but people think "70 degrees? That's wonderful!"). So I estimate the same model but instead replace `mean_temp_group` with `mean_high_group`:

```
event ~ age + sex + ... + mean_high_group
```

and the results don't match either my theory or what I saw with `mean_temp_group`.

That seems weird given how similar the two variables are. The average and average high variables have a correlation coefficient of 0.9939. In essence the average high is the average plus a constant (on average, 9.4 degrees with a standard deviation of 2.1).

At first I assumed this was a problem with the code, so I re-pulled the data (still have the same problem and the data extraction seems to be accurate). I also took the model with `mean_temp_group` and edited the formula in place to read `mean_high_group` lest I omitted/included a different variable between the models (I didn't).

I assume it has something to do with the binning or something along those lines - any ideas? I'm very confused by two variables that basically appear to be an additive shift of each other giving very different results.

Comment: Please show us exactly *how* the results don't match.  Are you referring to predicted log odds? The fitted coefficients?  Something else?  What regression diagnostics have you run?

Comment: "I don't expect the response to temperature to be linear" — Then use polynomial terms or a spline. Discretizing the temperature doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @whuber, the odd ratios in the model with average temperature are ~1 from 40-60 and then trend upwards maxing out at 1.15-1.20. They are ~1 for the entire range for the model with the average high temperature. I'm open to any diagnostics you have in mind.

Comment: @Kodiologist, I've been binning temperature and fitting fixed effects to get the flexibility that comes without imposing a functional form on the response. Normally, the chief trade-off with this approach is estimating a lot of parameters with a relatively small data set. In this case, I'm trying to estimate about 40 parameters with 55,000,000 observations and don't suffer as directly from that problem. I've considered estimating with something like GAM smoother but such an approach doesn't lend itself to hypothesis testing.

Comment: But you *are* imposing a functional form on the response, namely, a piecewise constant function with predefined breaks. The problem is not that discretization creates a lot of parameters but that it's extremely coarse. See also [Frank Harrell's piece here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous).

Comment: 55 million observations!?  I think we're going to need to see the summary output of both models.  With so many observations you can do far better than binning the temperature ranges, though, as @Kodiologist suggests.  The diagnostics I had in mind concern multicollinearity within each of the two sets of independent variables to see how reliable the estimates might be.

Comment: @Kodiologist - I agree with Frank Harrell on all of his points. It is why I was striving to have small intervals (5 degree steps) so that the assumption of constant within that range was not too much of a reach. The step between any two bins should be fairly small as well.  In theory, I could estimate an effect for each individual degree and reduce the problems with coarseness but that, of course, runs into problems with estimate accuracy. I'll try a polynomial approach on a sub-sample and see what happens. I'm sure the problem is related to the binning but I can't figure out how/why.

Comment: @whuber, do you want the coefs or the model level info? I have the output from broom::tidy() and broom::glance() at https://gist.github.com/iacobus42/db3cbdf54cae2595dace822ddcd2145e Multicollinearity with month has concerned me but hasn't seemed to be an issue. What confuses me with at possibility more generally is what is causing the effects of the two (basically identical less a constant) parameters to have massively different effects between the two models.

Comment: I understand that you bin these temperature variables; do you treat these new binned variables are ordinal or nominal? What serves as the reference level in both cases? Also, try running your test models with no variables aside the `mean/high_temp_group` and see what you get. You might induce some interaction with one of the other control variables unintentionally (and yeah, avoid binning if possible but that's another story).

Comment: When you define the reference category for each of your two predictors it presumably contains different people (or sites). Is that the problem?

Comment: @usεr11852, I've looked at the crude rate by 5 degree temperature bins (and 1 degree bins) for both mean and high temp groups. The mean model and mean raw-plot match up approximately (same general shapes with similar inflection points). The mean and high temp raw plots are basically a 10 degree shift of each other. I've redone the analysis as Penguin_Knight suggested with 1-degree bins as a test and it appears that the bin size was causing the differences. The ref in both the 5- and 1-degree bin size models is under 40 (for mean) and I've tried under 40 or 50 for the high model.

Comment: @mdewey, I thought the reference group was part of the problem. Since the reference group is defined as <= some temp in both models, it is rather large compared to any one of the 5-degree bins. I tried accounting for the fact that mean high exceeds the mean overall and considered various cut-offs for the high temperature model but wasn't solving any of the problems with the 5-degree bins. It does align with 1-degree bins though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some speculations. If we plot the coefficients of binned high temperature versus those of binned mean temperature we can see a curve linear relationship:

[image]

My guesses are:

i) While the correlation is high, the very high number of sample size might have masked some subtle non-linear relationship. In some climates, it's possible that there is a wider variability in summer compared to winter. In that sense, it's not like all cases are just moved to the next bin, there could have been some reshuffling, causing the difference.

ii) Following up with the point above, in the graph we can also see the associations with the outcome seems to be diminishing compared to that of the mean temperature. A possibility is that at a very high temperature (e.g. when a heat wave strikes,) people might change behaviors that mitigated their risk. For instance they may have stayed indoor and turned on the AC, so that they were less likely to get heat stroke or dehydration, etc.

And I think that the 5-degree binning approach seems a bit wasteful. With so many data points it may be worth to examine the association between temperature and the log odds of the events (can be done in single degree), and evaluate if binning really needs to be done, or can temperature be included in some other functional forms.

Comment: There is definitely behavior change driving the noise at the high temperatures (combined with the relatively small n at the edges). I went through and estimated the model on a 5% subset with 1-degree bins and that results in the two models giving similar results. I'm going to attempt to fit the model using the full dataset within 1-degree bins. The reshuffling idea seems to potentially explain the problem with the larger 5-degree bins.